# Запятая при уточнении

Tags: запятая

Построен и введен новый Дом культуры в селе Ново, сметной стоимостью 10 млн руб.
Нужна ли запятая перед "сметной". подобные предложения встречаются часто и везде пишут по-разному. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

> Построен и введен новый Дом культуры в
> селе Ново, сметной стоимостью 10 млн
> руб. Нужна ли запятая перед "сметной".

Нужна. Как минимум из-за наличия слова "новый"...

"Сметной стоимостью 10 млн руб" -- несогласованное определение к Дому культуры (Дом культуры КАКОЙ? -- сметной стоимостью 10 млн руб).

Определяемое слово (*Дом культуры*) имеет впереди стоящее согласованное определение (*новый*). Если не поставить запятую, можно будет понять, что и у ранее построенного Дома культуры сметная стоимость тоже составляла 10 млн руб. А теперь построили НОВЫЙ с такой же стоимостью.

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119 :

> **§ 53.** Несогласованные определения, выраженные существительными в форме
> косвенных падежей с предлогами и
> относящиеся к нарицательным именам
> существительным, обособляются:
>
> 1) если определяемое слово уже имеет
> впереди стоящие согласованные
> определения...

Comment: Тогда в предложении:В ООО " " построено животноводческое помещение на 200 голов сметной стоимостью 18 млн руб. - тоже нужна запятая?